# What is the probability of a poisson random variable less than its mean?

Tags: probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

I have a poisson random Variable $X$ with parameter $\lambda$. I need to find the value of $P(X \leq \lambda)$.

I know that, this is given by

$$P(X \leq \lambda) = e^{-\lambda} \sum_{x=0}^{\lambda}{\frac{\lambda^x}{x!}}$$

How to calculate further? I found an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/476326/516816) which says this value is 0.5, but it calculates the value numerically using a R script. Is it possible to calculate this value directly?
Thanks!

Comment: That answer only says that the value converges to $0.5$ as $\lambda$ tends to infinity.  There is probably no simple, exact formula for this sum.

Comment: The CDF of a Poisson distribution can be expressed in terms of the incomplete Gamma function: $$P(X\le k)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(k+1)}\int_{\lambda}^\infty e^{-t}t^k\,dt$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That formula is valid when $\lambda$ is an integer. In general
$$P(X\le\lambda)=e^{-\lambda}\sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor\lambda\rfloor}{\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}}$$
where $\lfloor\lambda\rfloor$ is the integer part of $\lambda$. This will not
equal $\frac12$ in general, but for large $\lambda$ will be approximately
$\frac12$.